# How to pass guid using TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, guid, tempdata

I am using TempData to pass the guid between two action methods within the same controller, but I am getting null in the second method where I am calling it.I am not able to figure out why I am getting a null value.
Here is what I could do so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordModel model)
{
     var uniqueIdForUser = db.Database.SqlQuery<RequestResetPasswordModel>("spResetPassword @param1", new SqlParameter("param1", user.ADMIN_USERNAME)).OrderBy(m => m.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
     TempData["uniqueIdForUser"] = uniqueIdForUser.Id;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordModel model)
{
     Guid uniqueid = (Guid)TempData["uniqueIdForUser"];
     return View();
}
```

Comment: When is the ResetPassword being called?

Comment: @BonMacalindong its a post method, its called when the user hits the submit button

Comment: So from the ForgotPassword view, you post it to ResetPassword? Put [HttpPost] on ResetPassword.

Comment: @BonMacalindong yes its there already,I dint post it here because I thought its not necessary to solve the issue

Comment: @sumedha Don't leave out code. Post your code there as is, we cannot see/think what you have done and not done. We can only see and judge from the post.

Comment: @BrendanVogt I have edited my post now. Please check

Comment: TempData value only exists for the next request only. So, in your case the tempdata value is available only when the ResetPassword action is called exactly after user makes request to ForgotPassword action. Probably in your case this might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `Session["uniqueIdForUser"]` for this, or even store the value with the user object somewhere in the database. The time between requesting the password reset and actually doing it could be long.

Comment: I have tried with session as well but it still gives me a null reference exception. I have already stored the value in the db table, but I want to compare the value in the session object and the db value, and accordingly update a record in the database

Comment: On which line (exactly!) does the NullReferenceException occur? If needed, add/edit your code in the question to show this.

Comment: its already there in the question, in the ResetPassword method when I am calling the session

Comment: That means either it was not put into the session, or a `null` value was stored, or the session was cleared. Note that during development, stopping and restarting the application will clear all sessions. Also double check your session keys; always best to use a Const instead of a string literal, just to rule that out.

Comment: I am using session the same way like I am using temp data. Storing the session like this: `Session["uniqueIdForUser"] = uniqueIdForUser.Id;` and retrieving it using: ` Guid uniqueid = (Guid)Session["uniqueIdForUser"];` Is there anything else I need to do

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am late here. Maybe you got some solution but for those who are in this problem.
Maybe

```
new GUID(Session["something"]);
```

will help